# Breaking a while loop in Arduino

Tags: while-loop, arduino, break

I have a program that moves a stepper motor to the right, left and have a stop button that stops the motor. In one part of my program, a motor gradually lowers a speed and stops after a certain period of time `iv`.
The problem is that in this part of a program (when a motor gradually lowers a speed and then stops) I can’t stop the motor upon pressing a stop button. I understand that I need to break a `while` loop somehow, but using a `break` statement doesn't wort for me.

Do you have some ideas?

Here is my function:

```cpp
/* --- STEPPER MOTOR ---*/
const int motor_step = 3;
const int motor_dir = 4;        
int stepSpeed = 0;
int stepMaxSpeed = 1000;        
int fadeAmount = 100;           
int fadeDelay = 10;

/* ---- STOP BUTTON ---- */
int buttonStop = 5;             
int stateStop=0;

void setup() {
  .
  .
  .
  stateStop = digitalRead(buttonStop);
}
void loop () {
  .
  .
  .
  myfunc();
}


void myfunc() {
  if(stateStop == HIGH) {noTone(motor_step); stepSpeed = 0;}

  elapsedMillis te;
  unsigned int iv = 1500;

  while (te < iv) {
     if(stepSpeed == stepMaxSpeed) {
       stepSpeed = stepSpeed+0;
       tone(motor_step,stepSpeed);
       digitalWrite(motor_dir,HIGH); 
     }
     else {
       stepSpeed = stepSpeed + fadeAmount;
       tone(motor_step,stepSpeed);
       digitalWrite(motor_dir,HIGH);
       delay(fadeDelay);
     }
     if(stateStop == HIGH) { stepSpeed = 0; break;}
   }
   if(stepSpeed == stepMaxSpeed) {
     while(stepSpeed>0){
       stepSpeed = stepSpeed-fadeAmount;
       tone(motor_step,stepSpeed);
       digitalWrite(motor_dir,HIGH);
       delay(fadeDelay);
       if(stateStop == HIGH) { stepSpeed = 0; break;}
     }
   }
   stepSpeed = 0;
   noTone(motor_step);
   digitalWrite(enable,LOW); // enable changed from HIGH
}
```

Comment: did you ever consider just making one of the variables in the while loop end the loop? Like say, setting `iv`, whatever that mystery name means, to something `<` the equally poorly named `te`, like `iv = 0`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an X\Y problem that easily solved without having to do what they are asking how to do.

Comment: Your question is an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us what problem you are trying to solve instead of asking for help with the solution, which does not appear to be the correct approach.

Answer (score -1):

Your `break` condition does never trigger as `stateStop` is never being updated inside your while loop. How is your program supposed to know? It's busy running the loop and does not care about anything outside it's scope.

Check the button state inside the while loops or use interrupts

Comment: Using interrupts is not my case, as two pins that are supposed to work with Interrupts are already used for stepper motor step and dir. However, I'll try to check a button state inside the while loop. Thanks